# Printing characters onto screen using Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

hi i'm using NASM in ubuntu 11.10 and wrote a program using it, following code will printout the exactly one character at a time.

```
    [BITS 16]       ;Tells the assembler that its a 16 bit code
    [ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will

    ;segment .data
        PROMPT1 db  "HELLO WORLD",0x0
        STAR    db  '*'
    ;segment .text
       ;global asm_main
    ;asm_main:
        mov     si, PROMPT1
        mov     al, [si]
        ;mov ecx, 11
    loop_start:
       call    PRNTCHR
       inc     si
       mov al, 0xA
       call PRNTCHR
       mov     al, [si]
       cmp     al, 0
       je      $+4
       loop    loop_start
       jmp         $

   PRNTCHR:
       MOV AH, 0x0E        ;Tell BIOS that we need to print one charater on screen.
       MOV BH, 0x00        ;Page no.
       MOV BL,0x0F        ;Text attribute 0x07 is lightgrey font on black background

       INT 0x10    ;Call video interrupt
       RET         ;Return to calling procedure

   TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0
   DW 0xAA55                   ;Add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

i do have two questions regard this code segments.

1. although star db '*' doesn't do anything in the code yet it's important.
2. printing new line doesn't work efficiently. program outputs spaces as well

can you help me out?

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute data (`db  "HELLO WORLD",0x0`) as code???

Comment: i want to print it terminal or qemu virtual hard like this.
h\ne\n..... \n indicates new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's in given an identifier it resides in the binary file as it is, after loading to origin the processor keeps on incrementing IP and running the code, the case of it printing when '*' is there is purely coincidental(when PROMPT1 being converted to instructions!). This won't happen when there is segmentation, but in this mode segmentation is not enabled by default, when porting segmented code in to non segmented code you should put the non code data stuff after code that you want to run it's simple as that, Thanks Alex(for do you want to *run*)!